# PHP file crashes after 5 sec of execution

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a mysql query which returns a list of movies from database.
The query is as follows

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$tableName` WHERE `$columnName` >= '$stDate' and `$columnName` <= '$endDate' and `$columnName` != '0000-00-00' and `$columnName` != '1970-01-01' ORDER BY `$columnName` ASC;";
```

The query is working fine perfectly as i have tested it using phpmyadmin

The main problem is that it only returns about 30 records.

if the no. of records to return are more then 30, then the php file crashes and returns nothing at all.

Through my research on google i have found out that these setting in php.ini needs to be changed. I have made the following changes and restarted the server.

```
max_input_time = 60;       to    max_input_time = 3600;
max_execution_time = 60;   to    max_input_time = 3600;
memory_limit = 64M;        to    memory_limit = 1024M;
```

But these changes does not solves the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: How are we supposed to help you, given that you've posted a working query and nothing else? The INI settings have nothing to do with your problem. They're already set to *60 seconds* and your script is crashing after *5 seconds*. How will increasing the limits help?

Comment: unless you're on an incredibly underpowered server, or dealing with large blob records, 30 records shouldn't even make php blink.

Comment: In your `mysql_query()` I assume that's what you're using , add this : `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Let us know if that prints anything out.

Comment: did you set the max_executio_time=3600? Or you have a typo in your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot meagar,Marc B,kylex and Aris for your precious time.
I have just figured out the problem.
and posting the answer as follows.

I had this as my local setting

ini_set('memory_limit', '1GB');

Which should be 

ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');


Sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to know without knowing more.

Looking at your query makes me think of some things:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$tableName` WHERE `$columnName` >= '$stDate' and `$columnName` <= '$endDate' and `$columnName` != '0000-00-00' and `$columnName` != '1970-01-01' ORDER BY `$columnName` ASC;";
```

**1.** Use RESERVED KEYWORD NOT (or IS NOT) instead of !=.

**2.** Why `$columnName` != '0000-00-00' and `$columnName` != '1970-01-01' ???

**3.** You shouldn't use semicolon at the end of the query. (if you're not adding queries in the same batch)

Please supply us with the whole code, at least where the actual query are executed and what values are put in to it...

Comment: I have accepted your answer.
but i figured out the problem already.

Thanks a lot for the time.
I appreciate it.

And will surely take your suggestion no. 1,3 for my further practise.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I got curious now. What was the problem?

Comment: Its a very silly typo problem.
Was using this
ini_set('memory_limit', '1GB');
instead of this
ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');